# PowerShell не ждать выполнения команды в цикле

Tags: powershell

Есть простой цикл в повершелл по запуску npx cypress проблема в том что хотелось бы что бы тесты запускались параллельно но цикл ждет ответа после каждого запуска и выполнение получается последовательное. как сделать так что бы команда запускалать и не дожидаясь ответа проходил весь цикл

```
[int]$Stress = 10

 Set-Location -Path  D:\test\

#Запуск
FOR ([int]$TestVar = 1; $TestVar -lt $Stress+1; $TestVar++){
    Write-Host "запускаем тест " $TestVar

     cmd.exe /c "npx cypress run --headed --spec D:\test\cypress\integration\StressTest\Test.spec.js"
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: ```foreach --parallel```? [тыц](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: можно попросить пример? у меня ошибки падают(

Comment: А с сайта пример чем не устроил(по ссылке), проверил он компилируется и работает...

Comment: при правке его под свои параметры получаю множество разных ошибок в зависимости от того как настраиваю. почитал так же про foreach-object там ситуация схоже. скорее всего я просто неправильно понимаю как это должно работать

Comment: Тогда стоит выложить ваши попытки и ошибки которые получаете, желательно в сам вопрос, ибо никаких проблем с его использованием я не замечал если делать по инструкции :) а гадать что вы изменили что оно начало ругаться - такое себе занятие, особенно не зная что именно за ```множество разных ошибок```